# Pass and display dynamic array in tectite form mail template

Tags: php, email-client

I am using Tectite Form mail to send emails in my project . The templates being used are files like
example1.email.html . I need to pass a dynamic array in the mail options from the PHP script to this template and then parse the array and show both the keys and values of the array in the template . How can I achieve this using Tectite Form mail . If this cannot be done using Tectite ,then request you to suggest some suitable email software

Comment: So you give Email address and template to `Tectite Form` and it sends email?

Comment: Yes , but I also need to pass an array of dynamic values to the Tectite Form and the keys and values of this array should be displayed in the email being sent

Comment: So like you want to set value for fields in template dynamically?

Comment: The fields and values will be the key and value in the array being sent by the PHP script

Comment: I don't know how we can achieve it using `Tectite Form` mail but we can modify template before sending it to `Tectite Form`.?

Comment: ok let me know how

Comment: Just share code of one template, tell me where you want to add this key values in template? and also share code where you gets template and pass it to `Tectite Form`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236959/discussion-between-webdev-and-navnath-jadhav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your template `$dynamicarray`

```
<html>
<body>
    //other html
    $dynamicarray
</body>
</html>
```

Your dynamic  array

```
$dynamicArray = array(
    "Peter"=>"35",
    "Ben"=>"37",
    "Joe"=>"43"
);
```

Generate dynamic html using array

```
$arrayHtml = "";
foreach($dynamicArray as $key=>$value) {
    $arrayHtml.="<p>".$key. " : ".$value."</p>";
}
```

Pass in data. which is used in while making API request

```
$data = "mail_options=".urlencode('FromAddr=xyz.com, HTMLTemplate=templateName.html').
"&dynamicarray=".urlencode($arrayHtml);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: I implemented the changes suggested by you . But one issue still remains , the dynamicarray is being printed as text and not as html in the browser

Comment: `$dynamicarray` as it is or its value without `<p>` tag?

Comment: its value with <p> tagg

Comment: means p tag is not rendering?

Comment: `$arrayHtml.=$key." : ".$value." \n";` Will this do our work?

Comment: Need to enclose this in html in order to format it. Ok let me try.

Comment: Used $arrayHtml.=$key." : ".$value." \n";